# How to remove the Additional Content From the NSString in ios

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

In my project i have saved the parsed JSON Response in a string,in that string has some additional strings how to remove that i already tried the NSString_stripeHTML File i get same Value only,
here is my Strings,

**First String**-

```
"&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;color: rgb(84, 84, 84); font-family: arial, sans-serif; font-size: small; line-height: 18.2000007629395px;&quot;&gt;Aashirvaad offers a range of product that includes&amp;nbsp;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-weight: bold; color: rgb(106, 106, 106); font-family: arial, sans-serif; font-size: small; line-height: 18.2000007629395px;&quot;&gt;Aashirvaad Atta&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;color: rgb(84, 84, 84); font-family: arial, sans-serif; font-size: small; line-height: 18.2000007629395px;&quot;&gt;, Aashirvaad Select Atta, Aashirvaad Multigrain Atta, Iodised Salt,Aashirvaad Spices,&lt;/span&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

Here "Aashirvaad offers a range of product that includes Aashirvaad AttaAashirvaad Select Atta, Aashirvaad Multigrain Atta, Iodised Salt,Aashirvaad Spices"

**Second String**-`&lt;p&gt;gram dall &amp;nbsp;is a dall&lt;/p&gt`
Here "gram dall is a dall"

**Third String**- 
`&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 16.1200008392334px;&quot;&gt;Channa is a genus of the Channidae family of snakehead fish. This genus contains 34 scientifically described species, but the most well known are probably the northern snakehead and the giant snakehead.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/p&gt;`

Here "Channa is a genus of the Channidae family of snakehead fish. This genus contains 34 scientifically described species, but the most well known are probably the northern snakehead and the giant snakehead."
Help me.

**Updated..**
JSON Response

```
{"success":true,"products":{"product":[{"product_id":"51","name":"Aashirvaad Atta","description":"&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;color: rgb(84, 84, 84); font-family: arial, sans-serif; font-size: small; line-height: 18.2000007629395px;&quot;&gt;Aashirvaad offers a range of product that includes&amp;nbsp;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-weight: bold; color: rgb(106, 106, 106); font-family: arial, sans-serif; font-size: small; line-height: 18.2000007629395px;&quot;&gt;Aashirvaad Atta&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;color: rgb(84, 84, 84); font-family: arial, sans-serif; font-size: small; line-height: 18.2000007629395px;&quot;&gt;, Aashirvaad Select Atta, Aashirvaad Multigrain Atta, Iodised Salt,Aashirvaad Spices,&lt;/span&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/p&gt;","Attributes":[{"attribute_group_id":"7","name":"Quality","attribute":[{"attribute_id":"12","name":"Quality","text":"medium"}]}],"meta_title":"Aashirvaad Atta","meta_description":"Aashirvaad Atta","meta_keyword":"Aashirvaad Atta","tag":"","href":"http:\/\/devunne.com\/shoppingstore\/index.php?route=product\/product&product_id=51","model":"atta","categories":[{"product_id":"51","category_id":"78"}],"image":"catalog\/aashirvaad-atta-whole-wheat-noworry.jpg","images":[{"product_image_id":"2448","product_id":"51","image":"catalog\/AttaFlour.jpg","sort_order":"1"},{"product_image_id":"2449","product_id":"51","image":"catalog\/AttaFlour1.jpg","sort_order":"2"}],"sku":"","upc":"","ean":"","jan":"","isbn":"","mpn":"","location":"","quantity":"120","stock_status":"Out Of Stock","manufacturer_id":"11","manufacturer":"Atta","price":"Rs.165","special":"110.0000","discounts":[],"options":[{"product_option_id":"228","product_option_value":[{"product_option_value_id":"20","option_value_id":"54","name":"500gm","image":"","quantity":"16","subtract":"1","price":"60.0000","price_prefix":"-","weight":"0.00000000","weight_prefix":"+"},{"product_option_value_id":"21","option_value_id":"55","name":"1kg","image":"","quantity":"51","subtract":"1","price":"0.0000","price_prefix":"+","weight":"0.00000000","weight_prefix":"+"},{"product_option_value_id":"22","option_value_id":"56","name":"2kg","image":"","quantity":"21","subtract":"1","price":"120.0000","price_prefix":"+","weight":"0.00000000","weight_prefix":"+"}],"option_id":"14","name":"Kilograms","type":"select","value":"","required":"1"}],"reward":"0","points":"0","tax_class_id":"0","date_available":"2015-04-16","weight":"0.00000000","weight_class_id":"1","length":"0.00000000","width":"0.00000000","height":"0.00000000","length_class_id":"1","subtract":"1","rating":0,"reviews":0,"minimum":"0","sort_order":"1","status":"1","date_added":"2015-04-16 16:51:26","date_modified":"2015-05-07 04:46:53","viewed":"6"}]}}
```

Comment: you need to access JSON using key... first create dictionary with key Products...

Comment: i parsed with Dictionary only

Comment: its fine. you just copy and paste my code.. after getting join response and see what string is in name variable.

Comment: please replay as early as possible...

Comment: i parsed correctly ,help me to remove the additional content From the Parsed string

Comment: i know you pared correctly. but this is JSON Data.. NO  need to store it in string. you must store it in dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first Convert Your NSString(description) to Proper HTML String and then you need to Use the NSString_stripHtml Files,

For String to HTML to Use this Link [MWFeedParser](https://github.com/rmchaara/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString%2BHTML.m)

```
  NSString *des=jsonResponse[@"description"];
//MWFeedParser-NSString+HTML & GTMNSString+HTML
 NSString *htmlString=[des stringByDecodingHTMLEntities];
//NSString_stripHtml
 NSString *description=[htmlString stripHtml];
```

Note:jsonResponse is your Response. This help to you

Answer (score 0):

Do not remove the HTML tags, just use the following method for trimming the HTML content:

```
-(NSString *)stringByStrippingHTML:(NSString*)str
{
  NSRange r;
  while ((r = [str rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
  {
    str = [str stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@""];
  }
  return str;
}
```

Comment: Can you please paste here the Original string? I mean your JSON response.

Comment: i shared my JSON response

Comment: I had used this, it s working perfectly. Your json response is not valid. Please validate it and check again.

Comment: @iDeveloper the json response is correct but he is storing all records in NSString. so it combine the HTML as well as other data. because of that your answer is not working. otherwise its ok.

Comment: i can Easily Convert the HTML to NSString  by NSString_stripHtml(Files), but in my response not Giving Exact HTML Content in Description it gives some other Data

Answer (score -1):

Try this....

```
NSDictionary *products=[jSONData valueForKey:@"products"];
NSDictionary *product=[products valueForKey:@"product"];
NSString *name=[product objectForKey:@"name"];
```

Note: JSONData is your response Data.. of NSData type.

Comment: @iOSDev i have posted my answer. try to access json data like this and print the name.. you will get the correct string.

Comment: @iOSDev  .. for and queries you can ask me.

Comment: NSDictionary *tempProduct=response[@"products"];
        NSArray *products=tempProduct[@"product"];
        for(NSDictionary *tempProductsObj in products)
        {productName=tempProductsObj[@"name"];} Like tis only we need to get the Name

Comment: both are the same things.. man. have tried my answer or not. i will definitely solve your problem.

Comment: @iOSDev Which error please tell me.i try to solve it.

Comment: -[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17d25d80 .. We need to Save that in array then only we Get the Value

Comment: @iOSDev i am update my answer. see it. just change the last line. inform me after doing change.

Comment: The `NSData` class doesn't have a `valueForKey:` method and anyway you should be using `objectForKey:` if it's a dictionary.

Comment: Well the sentence "Note: JSONData is your response Data.. of NSData type." is incorrect and the question's got nothing to do with JSON anyway.  The op wants to know how to strip-out garbage from a string contained within JSON.  And the answer to that is to not have the garbage there in the first place.

Comment: @trojanfoe JSONData is response data of type NSData is correct. i have run it.

Comment: No you haven't.  `valueForKey` will not work with it.

Comment: @trojanfoe i have asked you at which line you will get the error.

Comment: The first line.  You know the one you state is `NSData` and call `valueForKey` on.

Comment: @trojanfoe NSDictionary *products=[jSONData objectAtIndex:0]; try it and check it will give error on first line or not.

Comment: So `jSONData` is an array now?  Make your mind up.  Is it `NSData`, `NSDictionary` or `NSArray`?

Comment: its..  NSData only. it is response data.